# In what sutta/suttas did Buddha stated "I never admire samsara/bhava"?

Tags: sutras, samsara

I have read it somewhere and can't remember now. Buddha told Bhikkus that he never admires a disiple who stops his effort after attaining "sotapanna" state. He should still work hard until he is completely clean and attains Arhat status.

Comment: There are suttas where the Buddha "spits" on birth AND death and there is a Sutta where the sublime Buddha explained Ven. Ananda, why he did not taught much about the blessing of sotapanna (so that they would strive further. A combination... my person doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is probably a misinterpretation of this passage from Maha-Parinibbana Sutta:

> ... among these five hundred bhikkhus even the lowest is a
>   stream-enterer, secure from downfall, assured, and bound for
>   enlightenment."
>
> 1. And the Blessed One addressed the bhikkhus, saying: "Behold now, bhikkhus, I exhort you: All compounded things are subject to vanish.
>      Strive with heedfulness!"

```
Handa dani bhikkhave amantayami vo: Vayadhamma sankhara appamadena sampadetha.
```

And this one in regards to Samsara:

> “Just as even a little dung stinks, so I do not recommend even a
>   little becoming, not for so much as a finger snap”